# Share Image with Pre populated text on facebook in Android native app in latest SDK 4.0 later

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have browsed many places, didn't quite understand facebook SDK 4.0. Here are my thoughts and I would like you all to share your thoughts.

1. ShareDialog[Sharephotocontent] - Looks like I can only share images NOT Text attached to it.
2. ShareDialog[ShareLinkContent] - Looks like I can only share link with description and title with link.
3. What should we do when user is using older facebook apk which doesn't support sharedialog?

How do we achieve sharing images with description like a stamp card on left and text on write side in rectangular box.

Thanks a lot!.

Comment: What have you tried? the facebook sdk contains bundled projects that can help you with this. Moreover, this is documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#links).

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for share text and image on facebook wall. It's works.

Call facebooksharing method from your oncreate method as shown in bellow code.

```html
CallbackManager callbackManager;
private LoginManager manager;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
  setContentView(R.layout.Your_layout);
  callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  //call method for sharing post
  FaceBookSharing();
}

public void FaceBookSharing() {
List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
 manager = LoginManager.getInstance();
 manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);

 manager.registerCallback(callbackManager,
  new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    PostImage();
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancel() {
    System.out.println("onCancel");
   }

   @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
    System.out.println("onError");
   }
 });
}
private void PostImage() {
 Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    R.drawable.ic_launcher);

 SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image)
    .setCaption("Hey this is Demo post!")
    .build();

 SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(
    photo).build();

 ShareApi.share(content, null);
 Toast.makeText(this, "Succsesfully posted on your wall", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
 .show(); 
}
```